# Node.JS, async and Oracle DB: too many SQL attempts

Tags: node.js, oracle, async.js

With the following code like this:

```
async.eachSeries(records, function(record, cb) {
  oracle.executeSql("an sql statement", { param1: val },
  function(err, res) { console.log(err.message); cb(); });
});
```

I get the error output "SQL exec attempts exceed". I even get it for the first record the SQL statement is executed against. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does oracle come from? The driver from oracle (node-oracledb) doesn't have an executeSql method. Also, how many records are you talking about on average?

Comment: My bad, looks like executeSql wraps the standard node-oracledb query function. It is in-house. I'd say 300-500 records are meant to be processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error was coming from an in-house Oracle wrapper that had some problems. Using the Oracle driver functions directly fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Update 2019/06/26:

The driver, since version 2.2, has built-in support for batch SQL execution. Use connection.executeMany() for this when possible. It offers all of the performance benefits with less complexity. See the Batch Statement Execute section of the documentation for more details: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#batchexecution

Previous answer:

When working with many records, it's best to limit round trips by writing a little more code and using bulk binds. Here's an example...

Given these objects:

```
create table t (
  id    number not null primary key,
  prop1 number not null,
  prop2 varchar2(50) not null
)
/

create sequence t_seq;
```

The following should work:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const config = require('./dbConfig.js');

async function insertObjects(objs) {
  const start = Date.now();
  let conn;

  try {
    conn = await oracledb.getConnection(config);

    const prop1s = [];
    const prop2s = [];

    // Split the objects up into separate arrays because the driver
    // currently only supports scalar array bindings.
    for (let idx = 0; idx < objs.length; idx += 1) {
      prop1s.push(objs[idx].prop1);
      prop2s.push(objs[idx].prop2);
    }

    const result = await conn.execute(
      ` declare
          type number_aat is table of number
            index by pls_integer;
          type varchar2_aat is table of varchar2(50)
            index by pls_integer;

          l_prop1s number_aat := :prop1s;
          l_prop2s varchar2_aat := :prop2s;
        begin
          forall x in l_prop1s.first .. l_prop1s.last
            insert into t (id, prop1, prop2) values (t_seq.nextval, l_prop1s(x), l_prop2s(x));
        end;`,
      {
        prop1s: {
          type: oracledb.NUMBER,
          dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
          val: prop1s
        }, 
        prop2s: {
          type: oracledb.STRING,
          dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
          val: prop2s
        }
      },
      {
        autoCommit: true
      }
    );

    console.log('Success. Inserted ' + objs.length + ' rows in ' + (Date.now() - start) + ' ms.');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (conn) {
      try {
        await conn.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

function getObjects(count) {
  var objs = [];

  for (let idx = 0; idx < count; idx += 1) {
    objs[idx] = {
      prop1: idx,
      prop2: "Thing number " + idx
    };
  }

  return objs;
}

const objs = getObjects(500);

insertObjects(objs);
```

That uses the driver's execute method, but you can adapt to your wrapper. Also, while I use a one-off connection most applications should be using connection pools.